# Что такое спорная тревога?

Tags: поддержка, faq, тревоги

Одна из тревог в моем списке отмечена как «спорная».

Я впервые увидел в этом списке спорную тревогу, и мне интересно, что же такое спорная тревога? Как можно оспорить тревогу? Аналогично ли это тому, как если тревогу отметят неверной?

<sub>Свободный перевод: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/</sub>

Answer (score 8):

Тревога становится спорной, если она не была признана полезной, но и не была отклонена: участник сообщества просмотрел вашу тревогу, однако не выполнил каких-либо определенных действий. Основное назначение функционала – категоризировать тревоги в случаях, когда обоснованность тревоги нелегко определить.

Тревога может быть определена спорной в следующих случаях:

- тревога, содержащая спам или ненормативную лексику, была «*очищена*» модератором, но не была отклонена. Тревоги за спам или ненормативную лексику отличаются тем, что их «прямая» обработка может привести к нежелательным последствиям как в отношении автора сообщения, так и в отношении автора тревоги. Как результат, был создан специальный механизм очистки таких тревог, при котором ни автор сообщения, ни участник, отметивший его тревогой не получают наказания от системы;
- тревога «не является ответом» или «сообщение низкого качества» просмотрена в очереди проверок сообщений низкого качества, но сообщение отмечается как «выглядит нормально»;
- сообщение из очереди проверки голосов за закрытие было отмечено тревогой «рекомендовано к закрытию», но обработано как «выглядит нормально». Сама тревога остается активной.

Спорные тревоги не рассматриваются ни как полезные, ни как отклоненные независимо от действий, выполненных с ними.

#### В чем различие между спорными и отклоненными тревогами?

*Тревоги отклоняются если*:

- Модератор не соглашается с вами и отклоняет тревогу (для тревог содержащих спам, ненормативную лексику или тревог на комментарии).
- Вопрос отмечается тревогой на закрытие, попадает в очередь проверок на закрытие, и по результатам проверки ни один участник не голосует за закрытие.
- Тревога «не является ответом» и «сообщение низкого качества» для ответов, при отсутствии участников согласных с вами.

Слишком большое количество отклоненных тревог ведет к предупреждению участника или даже временному [запрету на право оставлять сообщения тревогой](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/).

*Тревоги отмечаются спорными если*:

- Вы отметили сообщение тревогой «не является ответом» или «сообщение низкого качества», но сообщение не было удалению автоматически, однако другой участник рекомендовал удаление сообщения.
- Сообщение было отмечено тревогой «спам» или «невежливый или оскорбительный», но тревога была отозвана.

Спорные тревоги рассматриваются как нейтральные, они не учитываются при наложении запрета на право отмечать сообщения тревогой.